# copy file using an URL from command line

Tags: windows

I have a batch script that is used to collect some data and upload that on other servers, using xcopy in a windows 7 command line. I want that script to collect some files that are on share point, so I need to get them using an URL and I need to login.

xcopy can't do the job, but are there other programs that can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you can bend [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) to download a file from a SharePoint site. If site is publicly available, it's all very simple. If not, you'll have to authenticate first, and this might be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

wget for windows maybe? http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Comment: This works perfect if I do like this: wget --http-user=XXX --http-password=YYY --no-check-certificate https://myUrl

Only drawback is that I need my password in clear text in my batch files. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: According to the manual you could store them in .wgetrc. http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTP-Options.html

Comment: Is .wgetrc a file? Where do I find it?

Comment: Yes it is a file. Look here: http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Startup-File.html#Startup-File. This is for *nix environments though, but I think it will find it, if it is in the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

The login part can be done using `CURL`, supplying the user name and password as `post` arguments. You can supply post args using `-d or --data` flag. Once you are logged in (and have required permission), you can fetch the required file and then simply transfer it using `xcopy` as you are already doing for the local files.